# Line break issue from CSV to MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, line-breaks

I am importing a .csv file into MySQL and everything works fine, except the line breaks that are in the file.

One of my .csv rows looks like this:

```
42,E-A-R™ Classic™ Earplugs,ear,images/ear/classic.jpg,5%,"Proven size, shape, and foam
3M's most popular earplug
Corded and uncorded in a variety of individual packs
NRR 29 dB / CSA Class AL",312-1201,,"E-A-R™ Classic™ Uncorded Earplugs, in Poly Bag",310-1001,,E-A-R™ Classic™ Uncorded Earplugs in Pillow Pack,311-1101,,"E-A-R™ Classic™ Corded Earplugs, in Poly Bag"
```

The sixth field over should break into a new line when called, but it doesn't. When importing the .csv I select *Lines terminated by* \r. I have tried \n and auto but no luck.

Weird thing is, the field looks correct in the database with all of the appropriate breaks. If I manually go in to insert the line breaks in PHPmyadmin it prints correctly. Each field is set to UTF-8 as well.

Any ideas on this? Thanks.

**edit**: here is the MySQL statement

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '/tmp/php89FC0F' REPLACE INTO TABLE `ohes_flyer_products`
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
ENCLOSED BY '"'
ESCAPED BY '\\'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\r'
```

Comment: What are you trying to import with initially, phpMyAdmin or console mysql?

Comment: I assume you mean the 6th field, that begins with "Proven size...

Comment: Can you also post the exact MySQL LOAD DATA statement you use?

Comment: I have the opposite problem, where I export data from MySql to use in Excel for reports, and fields that contain internal line breaks cause a line break for the row, resulting in a new row with data that should have been contained in the previous row. My solution is to use the pipe (|) character for line breaks, and convert everything in a text editor prior to use.

Comment: MySQL statement is in the main post now, and I'm importing with phpMyAdmin.

Comment: If I add \n at the end of each line in the .csv file it works, but that gets pretty tedious when there are a few hundred rows..

Comment: Is the CSV file coming directly from excel or is it coming from another source?  The point i am trying to get at is, do you know specifically that the CSV file is delimited by a \r or a \n and not a \r\n?  Also what version of phpMyAdmin are you on?

Comment: I initially made the file in Excel, but after encoding problems I opened it up in TextMate and saved it as UTF-8.

PHP version: 3.2.2
MySQL client version: 5.0.45

Comment: Can you try importing with a \r\n line delimiter on it?

Comment: I've tried that and it only returns one row rather than all of them. I think I read somewhere that on a Mac you only write \r

Comment: Windows = \r\n (excel created by M$) Mac = \r Linux \ Unix = \n.

Comment: There has to be a better way, but for now I just put a \n at the end of each line inside the .csv file (on Excel), then opened it up in TextMate to convert it to UTF-8. Quite the process..

Comment: @Carson: just to clarify, is your problem with PHP output from the Mysql row to HTML?  Browsers ignore the new-line characters except when text is within text boxes.  When outputting on a page, have you tried wrapping text in PHP's `nl2br()` function?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

maybe you could use [fgetcsv](http://php.net/fgetcsv) to parse each csv line into an array and then dump that array into the database?

something along the lines of

```
$fd = fopen($csvfile, "r");
while ($line = fgetcsv($fd))
{
    $sql = sprintf("INSERT INTO tablename (...) VALUES ('%s', ...)", $line[0], ...);
    $res = mysql_query($sql);
}
```

note 1: code not ready for production, check SQL injections!

note 2: please, use prepared statements as using them will speed the thing a lot (or make one multi-row insert statement).

note 3: wrap all in a transaction.

Answer (score 15):

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '/tmp/php89FC0F' REPLACE INTO TABLE `ohes_flyer_products`
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"'
ESCAPED BY '\\'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n'
```

Answer (score 1):

Your CSV file has some qualities that you might be able to exploit.

- The field containing carriage returns that do *not* terminate the record are enclosed in quotation marks.
- The carriage return denoting the end of record follows a record with data enclosed in quotation marks. If this is true for all records, it is a way to possibly distinguish mid-field carriage returns from record terminators.

Knowing this, here are some things you can try:

1. Using a program like [UltraEdit](http://www.ultraedit.com/) (or Notepad++) and its find/replace features (that include regular expression handling):

   - Find all carriage returns that are preceded by a quotation mark and replace them with a unique character or string. I suggest the pipe character "|" but first ensure they aren't used anywhere in the CSV file. These will represent end-of-record.
   - Next, replace all carriage returns with spaces. This will bring your fields with unwanted carriage returns back into alignment with the other data.
   - Finally, replace all special end-of-record characters with carriage returns. The end result that the only carriage returns present are end-of-record indicators.
2. Given that the carriage returns appear within a field that is enclosed by a delimiter (the quotation marks) you can specify that the import engine should only honor field and record delimiters *outside* of quotations. ([MySQL LOAD DATA INFILE syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/load-data.html)) Specifically, look at the `ENCLOSED BY 'char'` parameter. Since not all of your fields use the delimiter, you will need to specify `OPTIONALLY`. In theory you should be able to specify how the CSV file is constructed and not need to parse it beforehand. I am of the opinion, however, that the in-field carriage returns should probably be removed so that the text will properly wrap when output in new context.

Answer (score 0):

Your CSV appears to be non-standard, but that's often the reality of dealing with customer datasets.

As tools like MySQL's LOAD DATA statement are made to handle only the perfect use case, I've  found that dealing with non-standard datasets like this requires code.

One way to handle this is to first scrub your CSV, replacing mid-field line breaks with a special, unique string (like `===MIDFIELD_LINE_BREAK===`). Then I would write a custom CSV parser in a scripting language (Python, Ruby, PHP, Perl, etc).

In your CSV parser, iterate through lines in the file.  For each line:

- Swap the `\n` or `\r` characters back in for the `===MIDFIELD_LINE_BREAK===` characters.
- Construct and execute an INSERT statement.

Comment: That sounds like it would work, but it still involves manually entering the ===MIDFIELD_LINE_BREAK===. Instead I manually entered the \n and it seems to work. Thanks anyways.

Comment: I should've specified that when I said 'scrubbing', I meant for it to be automatic rule-based scrubbing (i.e. `join the next line until there are X unescaped/uncontained commas`).   I didn't know your data set was small enough to scrub manually, but I'm glad it worked out for you!

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
$query = <<<EOT

LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '$file' REPLACE INTO TABLE `$table`
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"'
ESCAPED BY '\\\'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\\\n'
IGNORE 1 ROWS;

EOT;
```

I had to tweak @Krunal's answer, due to getting errors, by adding a few extra forward slashes.

Unix line returns used here, by the way.

```
DOS:     \\\r\\\n
Old Mac: \\\r
Unix:    \\\n
```