# import csv into mysql does not work or return an error

Tags: mysql, csv, import

I have read through many similar questions on SE, but I can not sort out what is werong with my import. SQL does not return an error but 0/200 rows are uploaded. So I have a csv file with about 20x 12 columns. I have tried both with and without headers on the columns. I open mysql on the server and use the suggested import statement:

```
LOAD DATA INFILE "full_path_to_csv_file.filename.csv"
INTO TABLE users
COLUMNS TERMINATED BY ','
OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"'
ESCAPED BY '"'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
IGNORE 1 LINES;
```

I have tried both with and without the last line. I have tried removing the auto-increment column. I have all empty fields set to NULL...

.. and there are no errors, but 0 rows are uploaded.

I can't see what I'm doing wrong.

Help.

Comment: Does MySQL have access to the file on the server, or maybe it doesn't have read-access? Personally I prefer to just create an insert script, especially for relatively small files. You could try this plugin, which can convert a csv file to an SQL insert script https://github.com/BdR76/CSVLint/ or alternatively there is also this tool to convert to SQL insert script https://github.com/BdR76/datasetmultitool

Comment: Are you sure the lines are terminated by '\n'. If the file comes from a Mac or a Windows machine it would be '\r' or '\r\n' respectively.  Take a look at this answer unless you are sure this is a UNIX created file, in which case it should be OK with '\n'      https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4682965/line-break-issue-from-csv-to-mysql#4761714